# box2d: How do I rotate an object on specified amount of degrees smoothly

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

I wonder if box2d has some options for doing that?

I am trying to apply angular velocity atm, but don't know where to stop rotating :(...
So object which needed to rotate to 90 degrees, can't stop rotating....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it adding small angular velocity and comparing to current angle of the object... Not sure why I've asked the question. Everything worked well!